# Is it possible to bring fudge from New Zealand to UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, new-zealand, gifts

I have bought fudge for gifts in NZ but am now unsure whether I will be allowed to take it inti UK - will I?

Comment: Did you try looking at the [gov.uk page on brining food to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-food-animals-plants-into-uk/food)?

Comment: @Gagravarr That page isn't very helpful for fudge, since it offers no clues as to whether it's considered a "dairy" product or not.

Comment: It's a confectionary

Answer (score 4):

Turns out **you can bring any amount of fudge you wish to in the UK, as long as it is for personal use** (i.e. not for resale). Fudge should be a confectionery, and according to [UK customs rules](https://www.gov.uk/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports#food-from-outside-the-eu-details-of-restrictions)  confectioneries are exempt from import restrictions:

> ### Exempted food products
>
> The following products are exempted from the rules:
>
> [...]
>
> - chocolate and confectionery (but not if the sweets are made with high levels of unprocessed dairy ingredients)*
>
> [...]
>
> *Confectionery, chocolate or cakes (including Christmas cake, Simnel cake or cakes containing nuts) are permitted from any country as long as they are for your personal consumption and do not contain fresh cream or high levels of dairy products. Confectionery that contain high levels of dairy products include Burfi, Gulab Jaman, Halwah or Halva, Ras Malai, RasGullah, Ladoos, and Chum Chum.

Comment: Surely fudge *does* contain high levels of dairy products?

Comment: @e100 Makes sense. But it doesn't figure in the list according to the UK customs guidelines on the website. Probably because fudge *is* available in the UK. I would therefore try it anyway.